# Playing with pointer incrementation in C

Tags: c

I started playing a bit around in c when i found out that you can increment pointers.. So i thought, why not try to see if it's possible to clear my RAM with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int *pointer = &number;
    while (true) {
        pointer++;
        *pointer = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is the reason why this doesn't work my operating system, or does the C language have exceptions for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what world is this "not a real question"?  Some people are so darn close happy...

Answer (score 3):

> Is the reason why this doesn't work my operating system, or does the C language have exceptions for this?

It is undefined behavior as far as the language is concerned.  It is up to the OS to decide what happens when you muck with memory you don't own.

You allocated `sizeof int` bytes for `number`, store its address in a pointer, and then continue to walk past that block of memory until something obvious goes wrong.  As soon as you increment `pointer` and write to that location you invoke undefined behavior.

You cannot just read and write to random memory locations as you please (well, you *can*, your program just isn't guaranteed to behave in any certain way).

Comment: Hm okay. I just thought that this would clear my RAM and perhaps shut my system down when other programs started to get overridden or something.

Comment: @ThaPal: The behavior is undefined as far as the language is concerned, so you cannot reason about what will or will not occur. The OS will likely terminate your app with a segfault when you cross a memory boundary it knows you don't own, but again, you cannot  count on it.

Answer (score 3):

In any modern operating system, every process has its own address space. In it, it will find its own executable code and data. Therefore, you cannot simply access "the RAM of your computer". All you can do is mess things up in the address space of your program.

You can easily see this by running the following code in parallel:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    printf("The address of i = %p\n",&i);
    sleep(60);
}
```

You will (probably) see that all processes print out the same memory address. Of course, they are not pointing to the same physical bits of memory.

(**ps.** when shared libraries ("DLL") are loaded, you *will* have processes all pointing to the same physical bits in memory. That way, a lot of executable code has to be loaded only once for all processes. This will be read-only memory, so no process can alter executable code of other processes using the same library. The mechanism behind it is called memory mapping, have a look at the `mmap()` system call for more info.)

Comment: @iccthedral that's correct. On various OSes this example will clearly demonstrate that programs live in their own address space. And that accessing "the [entire] RAM of your computer" is not simply done by fiddling with a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`number` is declared on the stack, and you're wiping it and the subsequent memory locations. So you're corrupting the stack. This may or may not cause your program to crash; it's undefined behaviour. It's possible that the stack corruption could result in your function *appearing* to exit cleanly with no adverse effects, but it's much more likely that your process will SEGV when it tries to access an invalid memory location.

Comment: Just to add a bit of pedantry; C doesn't refer to a "stack".  It is an implementation detail for variables with automatic storage duration.  As far as C is concerned, anything can happen here.  of course, in reality, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

The thing called [memory protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) will prevent you from doing this. Basically, the OS will terminate the program if it tries to change the portions of RAM it had not been allocated, commonly known as [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

You can (in theory) do this when your program runs in privileged mode, such as when writing device drivers or programming for bare-metal embedded systems.

Comment: *"In theory"* anything can happen because this is UB

Comment: Running something like that in privileged mode sounds like a fun way to break my computer.  I'm not even being sarcastic.  What would be even better: Add a GUI that tries to explain what its doing, and instead of clearing the RAM in sequence, do it in random order.

Comment: @AJMansfield Even with memory-mapped I/O, you're quite unlikely to cause any permanent damage to the hardware. You will have to manually reflash the firmware in the worst case.

Comment: @Tibor I know it wouldn't take too long to fix.  By "break" I meant "render unusable".  The computer could certainly become unusable until I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to backup what others have already said, you program is going to most likely cause a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when you write into some memory location that is invalid or illegal.

To see that this is happening because of updating the contents of some random memory address I will show your program as run under GDB.

```
[jrn@localhost SO]$ gcc -ggdb dumb.c 
[jrn@localhost SO]$ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (GDB) CentOS (7.0.1-42.el5.centos)
Reading symbols from /home/jrn/source/SO/a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jrn/source/SO/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048399 in main () at dumb.c:9
9               *pointer = 0;
(gdb) list
4       {
5           int number = 0;
6           int *pointer = &number;
7           while (1) {
8               pointer++;
9               *pointer = 0;
10          }
11          return 0;
12      }
13
```

You will see on line 9 the error occurs when you are writing to some memory address that shouldn't be. The OS is using memory protection, often provided by the CPU, to detect the errant write.